# Allow parsing file-like URL routes

Tags: yii2, url-routing, yii-url-manager

Whenever I try and handle a route that looks like `controller/foo.xtn`, Yii complains `Unable to determine the path info of the current request.`. I want to handle these routes by converting `xtn` to an action parameter i.e. call `actionFoo($xtn)`, but also allow `controller/foo?type=xtn`. My plan is to write a UrlRule to define this behaviour, but how do I work around the path info parsing failure?

I'm using `enablePrettyUrl`, and would like to `enableStrictParsing` but for now I can deal without it.

Edit: What works and what doesn't -

```
controller/foo/abc?type=xtn ---> actionFoo('abc', 'xtn') # works
controller/foo/abc/xtn ---> actionFoo('abc', 'xtn') # works
controller/foo/abc.xtn ---> actionFoo('abc', 'xtn') # doesn't work
```

The error is thrown by [`getPathInfo()`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/web/UrlManager.php#L237) while attempting to parse `controller/foo/abc.xtn`, so it's being routed through Yii by the webserver.

Routing config (using PHP internal webserver for now):

```
<?php
// www/routing.php
if (preg_match('/\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])) {
    return false;
} else {
    include __DIR__ . '/../web/index.php';
}
```

Using the above config, I can see the PHP server sets the REQUEST_URI variable which is what Yii is reading.

```
'REQUEST_URI' => '/controller/foo/abc.xtn?app=4'
```

So I don't believe this is a webserver problem. Here is the only significant difference in $_SERVER arrays:

```
# fails in getPathInfo()
'REQUEST_URI' => '/feeds/strings/en.json?app=4',
'SCRIPT_NAME' => '/feeds/strings/en.json',
'SCRIPT_FILENAME' => '/Users/darvids0n/NetBeansProjects/php-web-services/web/www/routing.php',
'PHP_SELF' => '/feeds/strings/en.json',

# works
'REQUEST_URI' => '/feeds/strings/en?app=4',
'SCRIPT_NAME' => '/index.php',
'SCRIPT_FILENAME' => '/Users/darvids0n/NetBeansProjects/php-web-services/web/index.php',
'PATH_INFO' => '/feeds/strings/en',
'PHP_SELF' => '/index.php/feeds/strings/en',
```

If you read Yii's [source code](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/web/Request.php#L701), though, you will see that the lack of PATH_INFO does not actually factor into the failure to 'determine path info'.

Answer (score 2):

Unknown path should end up with 404. Trying to redirect it might be tricky, you have to be careful not to fall into loop.

You can add last rule in your list that will be the "last resort" path, something like

```
'<controller>/<action>' => '<controller>/<action>',
```

Any controller and action will work here.

For file extensions you can use suffix parameter for your rules.

```
[
    'pattern' => 'posts',
    'route' => 'post/index',
    'suffix' => '.json',
],
```

I would stick with one parameter name if you want to pass extension to action:

```
'controller/foo/<type:\w+>' => 'controller/foo'
```

So you need action like:

```
public function actionFoo($type)
```

Comment: Not sure I'm following you on how this helps. Regardless of my URL rules, one of the preliminary steps in routing the request is to call [`getPathInfo()`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/web/UrlManager.php#L237). This throws an exception before we even begin iterating the rules.

Comment: Oh, there is some problem with your server configuration in this case. Is it Apache? Could you paste your host settings if so?

Comment: Pasted routing config and a few other things.

Comment: Full $_SERVER dump would be handy here.

Comment: Posted. It's actually quite likely that there is something that can be fixed in the PHP routing but there isn't documentation around which demonstrates that functionality for PHP's server.

Answer (score 0):

```
// controller (site)
public function actionFoo($type) 
// rule
'site/foo<type:(\.xtn)>' => 'site/foo', //site/foo.xtn
'site/foo/<type:(\.xtn)>' => 'site/foo' //site/foo/xtn
```

Comment: Before answer, I checked - it works, probably you have conflict, put this rule in the 1st position. Yii version: 2.0.9. Also check if web server handles `xtn` as `php`

Comment: Same Yii version. I'm using PHP internal webserver to test this, could be a problem with that, except I do see a Yii error in the browser so it's still resolving everything through `index.php`.